# Ant:create JUnit report task programmatically

Tags: java, ant

I use the Ant API for creating tasks programmatically, but I have not yet found the class that create JUnit report task.
in short, I want  the equivalent of the code below using the Ant API:

```
<junitreport todir="..">
   <fileset dir="..">
      <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
   </fileset>
   <report format="frames" todir=".." />
</junitreport>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All task definitions are declared in ant.jar!org\apache\tools\ant\taskdefs\defaults.properties

Here is the JUnit-related ones:

```
junit=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask
junitreport=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLResultAggregator
```

Here is corresponding Java code may look something like this:

```
FileSet fs = new FileSet();
fs.setDir(new File(".."));
fs.createInclude().setName("TEST-*.xml");

XMLResultAggregator aggregator = new XMLResultAggregator();
aggregator.addFileSet(fs);
AggregateTransformer transformer = aggregator.createReport();
transformer.setFormat(Format.FRAMES);
transformer.setTodir(new File("..");
```