# Creating JUnit report programmatically

Tags: java, ant, junit

My current approach right now is from my application, just call the ant build and it will create the junit reports needed, but I want to have the flexibility to code junit reports programmatically.

I tried this approach
[Ant:create JUnit report task programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916717/antcreate-junit-report-task-programmatically?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
FileSet fs = new FileSet();
fs.setDir(new File(".."));
fs.createInclude().setName("TEST-*.xml");
XMLResultAggregator aggregator = new XMLResultAggregator();
aggregator.addFileSet(fs);
AggregateTransformer transformer = aggregator.createReport();
transformer.setFormat(Format.FRAMES);
transformer.setTodir(new File("..");
```

but I can't even get it running. Any more ideas?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Why didn't it run?

Comment: `FileSet fs = new FileSet();
fs.setDir(new File(".."));
fs.createInclude().setName("TEST-*.xml");

XMLResultAggregator aggregator = new XMLResultAggregator();
aggregator.addFileSet(fs);
AggregateTransformer transformer = aggregator.createReport();
transformer.setFormat(Format.FRAMES);
transformer.setTodir(new File("..");`

What should be the value of Format.FRAMES? Also when I run junit from the program, when will the code above be triggered?

Answer (score 1):

The code you've pasted is the equivalent of calling the junitreport task:

```
<junitreport todir="..">
<fileset dir="..">
<include name="TEST-*.xml" />
</Fileset>
<report format="frames" todir=".." />
</Junitreport>
```

You need to put this into a method and run it yourself. This code will take all files called `TEST-*.xml` and create a report with them. It will **not** create those files. Those files are created by the junit task in Ant. So you need to:

1. Run the junit task programmatically (see [JUnitTask (Apache Ant API)](http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/ja/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitTask.html)), ensuring that the TEST*.xml files are created in a temp directory somewhere.
2. Run the above code to produce the report, using those temp files.

The easiest way to do this is probably what you've done, to have a `build.xml` somewhere, and invoke ant directly. If the fileset you're using is stable, then this is probably the easiest way to go. Use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) java class for this.