# Create junit report programmatically

Tags: java, xml, ant, junit, report

I would like to create junit report programmatically using ant. I've seen that this question has been asked before here: [Ant:create JUnit report task programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916717/antcreate-junit-report-task-programmatically) and here: [Creating JUnit report programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381919/creating-junit-report-programmatically). My code is little different and I don't know where all that stuff goes.
My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myproject" default="junitreport" basedir=".">
    <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="./testreport">
            <fileset dir="./junitreports">
                <include name="*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="noframes" todir="./testreport"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>
```

Source code :

```
FileSet fs = new FileSet();
fs.setDir(new File("./junitreports"));
fs.createInclude().setName("*.xml");
XMLResultAggregator aggregator = new XMLResultAggregator();
aggregator.addFileSet(fs);
AggregateTransformer transformer = aggregator.createReport();
transformer.setTodir(new File("./testreport"));
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any error while running this ? Have you checked any tutorials online like this one : http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/ant/ant-and-junit.shtml

Comment: If I run this in cmd by calling "ant junitreport" everything works ok and html report is created in testreport directory, but I want it to be executed with java code. I need sample code, like the one in those other topics I provided, because my xml is different and it has more atributes, which I don't know where to put.

Comment: Ok, Have you checked this documentation, It is a Java implementation of junit ant task, It has all methods you need to run it from Java. http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/ja/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/JUnitTask.html

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but it doesn't provide the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the difference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916717/antcreate-junit-report-task-programmatically ?

Comment: The difference is in XML file. Mine XML has more elements and I don't know where and how to use them.

Comment: More elements ? <project> and <target> ? you don't need them to run programmaticaly the junitreport task.

Comment: So this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916717/antcreate-junit-report-task-programmatically should work for me to? The thing is that it doesn't.

Comment: Could you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and your project structure ?

Comment: This is my code:
`FileSet fs = new FileSet();
fs.setDir(new File("./junitreports"));
fs.createInclude().setName("*.xml");

  XMLResultAggregator aggregator = new XMLResultAggregator();
aggregator.addFileSet(fs);
AggregateTransformer transformer = aggregator.createReport();
transformer.setTodir(new File("./testreport"));`
I left out the format part, because it throws compilation error.
Project structure:
I have a two additionals folders in my project folder: junitreports folder, where xml files from tests are and testreport folder, where the html report should be created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have configured the junitreport ant task but you should also execute it.

```
Project project = new Project();
project.setName("myproject");
project.init();

Target target = new Target();
target.setName("junitreport");
project.addTarget(target);

FileSet fs = new FileSet();
fs.setDir(new File("./junitreports"));
fs.createInclude().setName("*.xml");
XMLResultAggregator aggregator = new XMLResultAggregator();
aggregator.setProject(project);
aggregator.addFileSet(fs);
AggregateTransformer transformer = aggregator.createReport();
transformer.setTodir(new File("./testreport"));

target.addTask(aggregator);
project.executeTarget("junitreport");
```

Comment: +1 You rock, nicely done. Thank you for taking the time to answer this question.